# Powerquery to recognise timestamps belonging to shift that straddles two consecutive dates

Tags: excel, date, time, powerquery

I have data in an excel table, generated by some software we use on site, the report is timestamped like this

6/05/2018  6:23:00 AM

As we are a 24 hour operation, I need PowerQuery to be able to recognise that the timestamps from 12:00:00 AM to 7:00:00 AM belong to the night shift of the previous day.

The problem I am facing is that although PowerQuery can handle Date/Time as a data type, it is seems to be truncating the time when importing data, so that the result for the above example within my query (and obviously in my output) is

6/05/2018  12:00:00 AM

Most of the stuff I can find on the net is about how to strip the time away - I want to keep it!!!

The purpose of this is so I can display records in chronological order for a night shift of production in a pivot table. At the moment I am having to add another column with the time alone, which causes data from midnight to 7:00am to preceed data from 7:00pm to midnight - when in fact it occurred after.

Cheers,

Mat

Edit: adding pictures of my problem, as I type I cannot see the images in the thread so I hope they are in the correct spots!

Example of my source data, timestamp is in the "Time" column.The other date columsn on the right are me getting something working so at least I have the shift date and the actual time together.

[Source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxl8.png)

The following is my query, there is a lot in here that appends the source location to a predefined set of attributes, basically what I am struggling with is that the "Time" field gets imported, but loses all the data after the decimal point so I just get a date. I want to keep that time appended to that date, as well as have another field which is the shift date as described above.

```
let
    // Removes unwanted characters.
    CharsToRemove = List.Transform({33..45,47,58..126}, each Character.FromNumber(_)),
    // The query is all based on the current month's portion of the current 13wk. 
    Source = Location_Data,
    // Set some data fields, not all are changed here as it affects later calculations.
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group Name", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Waste tonnes", type number}, {"Total Ore Tonnes", Int64.Type}, {"Dil cu_pct", type number}, {"Dil au", type number}, {"Dil ag", type number}, {"Dil fe_pct", type number}, {"Dil zn_pct", type number}, {"Density", type number}, {"Material", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Active from", Int64.Type}, {"Active to", Int64.Type}, {"Comments", type text}}),
    // This steps add the MTD trucking data, and correlates it with our claim grades and density based on two fields, "Name" and "Material".
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Name", "Material"},LoadTrak_Data,{"Load Origin", "Material"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    // This step expands the trucking data so we can work with the each column individually, such as truck ID, Date/time, Load Volume, etc.
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Record", "Time", "Dir.", "Operator", "Truck ID", "Load (m3)", "Truck Operator", "Crew", "Shift", "Material", "Load Origin", "Dumped At", "Day", "Shift Time", "Calc Shift"}, {"Record", "Time", "Dir.", "Operator", "Truck ID", "Load (m3)", "Truck Operator", "Crew", "Shift", "Material.1", "Load Origin", "Dumped At", "Day", "Shift Time", "Calc Shift"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded NewColumn",{{"Time", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Record low to high" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type3",{{"Record", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Error Volume Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Record low to high", "Error Volume", each if [#"Load (m3)"] = null then "28.2" else null ),
    #"Changed Error Volume to decimal number" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Error Volume Column",{{"Error Volume", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Error Volume to decimal number", "DMT", each if [#"Dir."] = null then null else if [#"Load (m3)"] = null then ([Error Volume]*[Density] * 0.7) else [#"Load (m3)"] * [Density] * 0.7),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Level Loaded", each if [Load Origin] = "Empty" then 0 else (Text.Start([Load Origin],4))),
    #"Creates shift date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Shift Date", each if [Shift Time] is null then null else if [Shift Time] < 0.2916 then [Time] -1 else [Time]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Creates shift date", "Correct location", each if [#"Dir."] = null then null else if ([Shift Date]) < ([Active from]) or ([Shift Date]) > (([Active to])+0.999999) then "No" else "Yes"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Level Loaded", type number}}),
    #"Level Dumped" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Level Dumped", each if [Dumped At] = "ROM" then 5270 else if [Dumped At] = "PAF" then 5170 else if [Dumped At] = "Paste" then 5270 else if [Dumped At] = "Waste" then 5270 else Text.Start([Dumped At], 4)),
    #"Change Level Dumped to decimal number" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Level Dumped",{{"Level Dumped", type number}}),
    #"Added TKMs column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Change Level Dumped to decimal number", "TKMs", each if [Dumped At] = "Waste" then (((([Level Dumped] - [Level Loaded])*7)+300)/1000 * [DMT]) else if [Dumped At] = "ROM" then (((([Level Dumped] - [Level Loaded])*7)+150)+300)/1000 * [DMT] else if [Dumped At] = "PAF" then (((([Level Dumped] - [Level Loaded])*7)+150)+300)/1000 * [DMT] else if [Dumped At] = "Paste" then (((([Level Dumped] - [Level Loaded])*7)+150)+300)/1000 * [DMT] else (([Level Dumped] - [Level Loaded])*7)/1000 * [DMT]),
    #"Changed TKMs to decimal number" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added TKMs column",{{"TKMs", type number}}),
    #"Filtered Correct Location to remove incorrect duplicates" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed TKMs to decimal number", each [Correct location] <> "No"),
    #"Added load count helper column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Correct Location to remove incorrect duplicates", "Load", each if [Correct location] = "Yes" then 1 else ""),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added load count helper column", each true),
    #"Filtered non-null Group Name rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [Group Name] <> null and [Group Name] <> ""),
    #"Converts date fields to type date" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered non-null Group Name rows",{{"Active from", type date}, {"Active to", type date}, {"Time", type date}, {"Shift Date", type date}}),
    #"Merged with Sched_13wk" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Converts date fields to type date",{"Name", "Material"},Sched_13wk,{"Name", "Material"},"Sched_13wk",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Sched_13wk" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged with Sched_13wk", "Sched_13wk", {"Dil cu_pct", "Material", "Scheduled Tonnes"}, {"Sched_13wk.Dil cu_pct", "Sched_13wk.Material", "Sched_13wk.Scheduled Tonnes"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Sched_13wk",{{"Shift Time", type time}, {"Day", type date}, {"Time", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Urgghhh that looks horrible, not sure how better to include it though. Lol the notes in there are to remind me what I am doing when I have to edit it. Still not finished, wanting to add a load more so that if I were to change position, the nest person sitting in my chair will have an idea of what is happening in the query!

And this is how the data is in the query output, see that all time values are gone.

[Output with no time values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCFCY.png)

Okay I really hope that helps. As you have guessed I am not a programmer by trade!

Report data which is copied into my excel workbook, with additional info typed in and then queried
[Report generated by software which is copied and pasted into workbook containing query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvHea.png)

Comment: As long as the datettime in included in a single value, it shouldn't be a problem.  The difference between 2 datetimes ( times 24 ) is the number of hours between.  Perhaps a `datediff` function would be the best way in Poiwer Query.  It's impossible to give you a specific answer without **seeing what you have** and **where the problem is**.  Also, how is the [tag:m] modelling language relevant to the question?

Comment: Cheers, I am just about to knock off but will upload some info tomorrow. Will investigate the datediff function as well.

Comment: There are other q on this site about this - need to search : similar one within the previous 4 days....

Comment: Hi Mike, pity you didn't include a link in your comment as I obviously did not find the thread before I posted. I will try to re-search and see what happens. If you are interested in helping it would be great if you could direct me!

Comment: I thought you wrote the data came from a `CSV` file.  Your `Source Data` appears to be Excel Table.  Using a Date/Time stamp in the format you show in a csv file, I cannot reproduce your truncation problem with Power Query.  And what you show in your screen shot of `Source Data`, in the `Time` column, is a date/time stamp formatted as `General` instead of one of the date/time formats.  Please clarify your problem, as it's cause is not at all clear.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks a lot for having a look. You are indeed right, I had assumed that the data was in .csv however it is not. I ran another report and i think that maybe it is just text that looks close enough to a timestamp for excel to interpret it as such. I then copy this and paste it into the "source data" that I have attached above. I will add an image of the report presently. Thanks a lot for pointing that bit out, I have been searching for answers with .csv which probably has not been helping me!

Comment: Regarding the "source" image I posted above, I thought leaving the format in general would help people work out what the problem was, obviously not! In any case when I copy from the report and paste into excel I can then treat them like a timestamp. Perhaps the problem though is that they are not a true timestamp to begin with?

Comment: **Don't** copy/paste.  Better to import the file using PQ.

Comment: Awesome, we will soon be attaching the data that is currently being manually input via in cab consoles in each truck. I imagine this can then be sucked through all together and matched up with the relevant data in the query. If the copy/pasting is the problem it will obviously be eliminated once the in cab consoles are working. Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. I had no idea that the copy/pasting would be the cause of the problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be resolved by using Power Query to **import** from the original text file.  You should be able to resolve the timestamp issues, as well as more easily format the results.

Copy/Paste is frequently NOT the best way to handle this sort of problem.

Comment: Sweet, for someone who does not do this sort of thing as a day job it is really nice to have someone you have never met come on and try to help, instead of just go out of their way to tell you everything you have done wrong and then rush to the downvote button without even giving you a hit of what to do next! Thumbs up for being a rad dude!!